# How to pass login name to login screen when using SAML

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, onelogin

We are using SAML based authentication. When we do the redirect to the OneLogin login page we already know the login name of the user. Is there a way to pass this information to the login screen e.g. as parameter, so that the user does not have to type it in twice?

Answer (score 0):

The SAML protocol has support for it by including a `<saml:Subject>` element in the `<samlp:AuthnRequest>` sent to the server. If you can make it work depends on if

- Your SP implementation supports adding it to the generated `<samlp:AuthnRequest>`
- Onelogin supports reading it.